# Verilog shift extending result?

Tags: verilog, hdl, synthesis, flip-flop

We have the following line of code and we know that `regF` is 16 bits long, `regD` is 8 bits long and `regE` is 8 bits long, `regC` is 3 bits long and assumed unsigned:

```
regF <= regF + ( ( regD << regC ) & { 16{ regE [ regC ]} }) ;
```

My question is : will the shift `regD << regC` assume that the result is 8 bits or will it extended to 16 bits because of the bitwise `&` with the 16 bit vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shift sub-expression itself has a width of 8 bits; the bit width of a shift is always the bit width of the left operand (see table 5-22 in the 2005 LRM).

However, things get more complicated after that. The shift sub-expression appears as an operand of the `&` operator. The bit length of the `&` expression is the bit-length of the largest of the 2 operands; in this case, 16 bits.

This sub-expression now appears as an operand of the `+` expression; the result width of this expression is again the maximum width of the two operands of the `+`, which is again 16.

We now have an assignment. This is not technically an operand, but the same rules are used; in this case, the LHS is also 16 bits, so the size of the RHS is unaffected.

We now know that the overall expression size is 16 bits; this size is propagated back down to the operands, except the 'self-determined' operands. The only self-determined operand here is the RHS of the shift expression (`regC`), which isn't extended.

The signedness of the expressions is now determined. Propagation happens in the same way. The overall effect here, since we have at least one unsigned operand, is that the expression is unsigned, and all operands are coerced to unsigned. So, all (non-self-determined) operands are coerced to unsigned 16-bit before any operation is actually carried out.

So, in other words, the shift sub-expression actually ends up as a 16-bit shift, even though it appears to be 8-bit at first sight. Note that it's *not* 16-bit because the RHS of the `&` is 16-bit, *but* because the entire sizing process - the width propagation up the expression - came up with an answer of 16. If you'd assigned to an 18-bit `reg`, instead of the 16-bit `regF`, then your shift would have been extended to 18 bits.

This is all very complicated and non-intuitive, at least if you have any experience of mainstream languages. It's explained (more or less) in sections 5.4 and 5.5 of the 2005 LRM. If you want any advice, then never write expressions like this. Write defensively - break everything down to individual sub-expressions, and then combine the sub-expressions.